# how to send notification to other users

Tags: jakarta-ee

i spend a lot of time thinking how can I  implement notification using primefaces push , i dont find the logic of the  implementation , can anyone help me please , i do this work in my gradueted project.

my collaborative application is a shared editor , to do that i integrate ckeditor with togetherJS, this application assit users from different cultures.

now i need to do notification about the language , for example , when a user connect , he choose the langauge (arabe, or french, or english) , when two users show the same language , the system notify the third user about the language used by the others.

my problem , i dont found how to identify the users and identify the user that choose a language different from the others , and how send notification to this user using primefaces push .

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces push is very very easy..
Let me try to clear it out..

You need to put this in your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class> 
     <async-supported>true</async-supported> 
</servlet>
```

Then you just need to go like in primefaces page example(Try Counter)
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/counter.xhtml

You need to subscribe into channel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
</script>
```

Second thing is just create the bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class GlobalCounterView implements Serializable{

    private volatile int count;

    public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public void increment() {
    count++;

    EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish("/counter", String.valueOf(count));
}
}
```

And create resource listener

@PushEndpoint("/counter")
    public class CounterResource {

```
@OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
public String onMessage(String count) {
    return count;
}
}
```

This should be enough..

Every one that will be in the page.. Will sucbscribe to the channel.. And every message that sent to channel will be notified when someone will raise the counter

Once this will work you will just need to use language channel for diffrent user.. When a user choose language you will subscribe to diffrent channel(Like counter- en,es etc..)

So once user is log in some language a message will be sent to all users that subscribed to channel of the language

Simpe.. Hope that helps

Edit:
http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/code-blogs/1298/using-primefaces-primepush-with-tomcat-7

This link also can help you..

Comment: Thanks Aviad for your reply , It's very helpful                                    primefaces push send notification to all subscribers, but i want to send a notification to a specific user .How can i resolve that.          thanks

Comment: You will create channel for each userId.. And if you want to send notification to userId just send to that channel